# Can you plug a CMOS camera (like the iPhone 8 back camera) into an mPCIe in a laptop?

Tags: sensors, computer-vision

I read that 12 megapixel iPhone cameras don’t record video in 12 megapixels because the processors are not able to keep up. It seems though, that if I could plug the CMOS sensor to the CPU of a laptop, I could process all 12 megapixels at 60 fps.

The only other problem would be that plugging the camera in through USB would be too slow since USB 3.0 is only 600 MBps. Instead, I want to use the mPCIe slot the wireless module goes into.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible as long as you are willing to spend a couple of million dollars to develop a MIPI to PCI-E interface board.

If you are just trying to use the camera on your broken iPhone, forget about it.

If you really need high speed 12M pixel camera, use machine vision cameras. Ethernet version is faster than USB.

Anyway, you need an "interface board", to connect a cmos to your computer. Machine vision cameras already have it inside either for pcie or ethernet.